# Web site administration tools error

Tags: asp.net

I want use ASP.NET configuration in Visual Studio 2012 C#, but the browser shows an error message:

> "An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again."

What happen with this, any solution?

Comment: What is the version of Visual Studio you use ?

Comment: im use visual studio 2012, OS Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

Here is some solutions I know ,

- Check aspnetdb.mdf under the App_Data subfolder.
- Set the default
  browser within Visual Studio to internal browser.
- Debug (F5) and then try again.